# Linux bash printf format with color assign to variable

Tags: linux, bash, printf

I just want a String (including coloring) be formatted by printf command and assign the result to a variable.

Without assigning it to a variable it works fine, but as soon as I assign the result to a variable and write the result, the format is gone.

My example:

```
RED=$'\033[0;31m'
NC=$'\033[0m'

INPUT="AB${RED}CD${NC}EF"

printf -v OUTPUT '| %-20s | %-25s| %-10s' " $INPUT " " OTHER " " TEST "
echo $OUTPUT

OUTPUT="$(printf  '| %-20s | %-25s| %-10s' " $INPUT " " OTHER " " TEST ")"
echo $OUTPUT

OUTPUT=$(printf  '| %-20s | %-25s| %-10s' " $INPUT " " OTHER " " TEST ")
echo $OUTPUT

printf '| %-20s | %-25s| %-10s' " $INPUT " " OTHER " " TEST "
echo ""
```

I found several solutions for passing the result to a variable (-v VARIABLE), but it looses the format.

Thanks for your help and many greetings,

Hauke

**EDIT 1: Also one problem seems to be the colorcode. printf counts 
AB${RED}CD${NC}EF as 17 characters instead of 6.**

Comment: Have you tried: `myvar="$(printf "AB${RED}CD${NC}EF")"` then using `myvar`?

Comment: It works fine on my shell. What system / versions / environment settings do you have?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, 
GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
2.6.38-13-server #53~lucid1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 29 13:12:12 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @slash4: What environment setting do you have? Maybe something is missing on my system, but strange thing is, that is is working with printf but not with echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this (**echo "$VAR" in ""**) to keep the formatting. The different ways of assigning the variable make no difference:

```
printf -v OUTPUT '| %-20s | %-25s| %-10s' " $INPUT " " OTHER " " TEST "
# or
OUTPUT=$(printf  '| %-20s | %-25s| %-10s' " $INPUT " " OTHER " " TEST ")
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

Comment: Thanks!! That helped.

Do you have an idea how I could solve the problem that printf interprets the colorsequence as an string?

Comment: Perhaps `echo -e "$var"`?